# Create matrix from smaller matrices in R

Tags: r

Is there a general function to build a matrix from smaller blocks, i.e. build matrix

```
A B
C D
```

from matrices A, B, C, D?

Of course there is this obvious way to create an empty big matrix and use sub-indexing, but isn't there anything simpler, easier and possibly faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some base R solutions. Maybe you can use

```
M <- rbind(cbind(A,B),cbind(C,D))
```

or

```
u <- list(list(A,B),list(C,D))
M <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x) do.call(cbind,x),u))
```

**Example**

```
A <- matrix(1:4,nrow = 2)
B <- matrix(1:6,nrow = 2)
C <- matrix(1:6,ncol = 2)
D <- matrix(1:9,nrow = 3)
```

such that

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    2    4    6
[3,]    1    4    1    4    7
[4,]    2    5    2    5    8
[5,]    3    6    3    6    9
```

Comment: Oh wow, how could I miss this!!!! :-o :-D I am using cbind/rbind constantly for vectors and it didn't click me LOL :-D Thanks :-)

Comment: @TMS welcome! I added another solution using `do.call` and `map`, which would be easier when with more small blocks